# video.js update video upon complete

Tags: jquery, html, video.js

I am attempting to grab the most recent mp4 file on my DB - play it - and upon completion repeat the process. However, the same file loops over and over.  It should be noted that I've checked my web service & each time the service is requested it does give me the new file as expected.

Is there a different way to update the video player?  I would prefer to avoid using the dispose method and re-creating the whole player if possible.

```
 videoURL = '/myService/get/' + sensorID + "?math=" + Math.random();

    _V_("video_player").ready(function() {
        var myPlayer = this;

        myPlayer.src({
            type : "video/mp4",
            src : videoURL
        });

        myPlayer.load();

        this.on("ended", function() {
            myPlayer.src({
                type : "video/mp4",
                src : videoURL 
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I presume the random number is there as a cache-buster. However your `videoURL` wouldn't change from one iteration to the next. You'd need to generate a new URL each time, e.g.

```
this.on("ended", function() {
  videoURL = '/myService/get/' + sensorID + "?math=" + Math.random();
  myPlayer.src({
    type : "video/mp4",
    src : videoURL 
  });
});
```

Comment: Staring at it I didn't see it.  Sure enough that was the issue.  And yes, it's a cache buster because I like the piece of mind